# How to render a string using jinja2 while making use of environment variables

Tags: python, jinja2

I would like to render a multi-line string that is included in-line in the code (not in an external file).  I would also like to enable certain environment variables including trim_blocks = True.

Every example in the jinja2 documentation includes loading an environment which then requires you to load templates using files.  This is not what i need.

Here is a approx example of what i am looking for:

```
Environment.lstrip_blocks = True
Environment.trim_blocks = True

template = Template("some string content") 
return template.render({'items': queryset})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass the necessary parameters to your `Template` call:

```
template = Template("some string content",
                    lstrip_blocks=True,
                    trim_blocks=True)
```

Or you can use the [`from_string`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/api/#jinja2.Environment.from_string) method of your environment:

```
template = Environment.from_string('Some string content')
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  That is quite simple.  This was not obvious to me when looking at the documentation